# Container view's collectionVC blocked with Parent's tapGesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an extension of UIViewController as follows to dismiss the keyboard if the user taps on the screen. Within this view I have a scroll containing textfields and two container views. The container views contain a collectionView. I want my overall viewController to dismiss when tapped around but I still want my collectionView's didSelectitemAtIndexPath to trigger. How can I achieve this?

```
public extension UIViewController {
    public func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    public func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

and

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        logViewLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewSearchVC") as! CollectionViewSearchVC
        controller.type = "SC"
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        controller.delegate = self
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        subContractorVC = controller

        let employeeController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewSearchVC") as! CollectionViewSearchVC
        employeeController.type = "V"
        employeeController.delegate = self
        addChildViewController(employeeController)
        employeeController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        employeeContainerView.addSubview(employeeController.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            employeeController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: employeeContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            employeeController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: employeeContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            employeeController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: employeeContainerView.topAnchor),
            employeeController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: employeeContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        employeeController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement the delegate methods for the GestureRecogniser in your ViewController and check for the class which is being touched, if that is of kind UICollectionView, then ignore that touch and let it do the default behaviour, i.e didSelect otherwise allow tap.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap!)
}

public func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    dismissKeyboard()
}

@objc public func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}


class RegisterVC: ParentViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tap?.delegate = self
// YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE
}
// NEW CODE ADDED HERE
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    print("shouldReceive")
    print(gestureRecognizer.view as Any) // CHECK FOR WHICH CLASS YOU ARE GETTING HERE WHEN YOU CLICK ON COLLECTIONVIEW
    if (gestureRecognizer.view?.isKind(of: UICollectionView.self))! {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
}
```

Try it and share the results.

Comment: whereabouts to I put the keyboard dismiss code. I added the delegate method you suggested. When I use my existing code i.e. self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround(), the keyboard gets dismissed on touch and collectionview didselect is not triggered. When I leave that line out. The collectionview delegate is called but the keyboard dismiss does not happen

Comment: in your viewDidLoad of RegisterVC, you can add self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround(), which is existing there. So, now the next thing you should check for is, the  print("shouldReceive")
print(gestureRecognizer.view as Any), the view you are getting, check my edits.

Comment: OK not getting any prints at all. I need to explicitly define regvc as the gesture delegate. How do I do this? Note my original func that extends UIViewController is a UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: You can create a parent class and inherit your RegisterVC or any other classes that need tap to hide feature from ParentViewController, check my edits

Comment: Thanks I tried your edits.. Now I am getting the prints from gestureRecognizer. My collectionView is paart of a container view so when I select that, the type is UIView. How to get around this?

Comment: You can set the tag = 100 in your storyboard to the ContainerView from storyboard and then compare the tag of gestureRecognizer.view?.tag == 100, and keep rest as it is

Comment: this leads to the same issue. I am getting a tag of 0 everytime i.e. the UIView(ContainerView), the collectionView within that container has a tag set but the RegisterVC gesture recogniser tap picks up the tag/view type from the containerView

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view behind the child VC's views and add the gesture to it

Comment: how can I add this gesture recogniser to my scroll view?

Comment: Can you add a bit more info on how to implement your solution? My container view is just a collectionView which is pinned to the top, left, right and bottom of its VC

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate of `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view controller and implement `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch)` as follows:

```swift
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if <<your collection view>>.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: <<your collection view>>)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```